# Image doesn't display when I changed the Image name into dynamic

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, images

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="ImageController" showheader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form>
      <apex:image url="{!imageURL}">
    </apex:image></apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class ImageController {
 public String imageURL{get;set;}

  public ImageController()
  {
    imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
    List< document > documentList=[select name from document where 
                                    Name='SamplePic'];

    if(documentList.size()>0)
    {
      imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
    }
  }
}
```

How can i can make the image name into dynamic?.. 
Meaning the name is based on the  then pass to apex controller.

I tried this but still now working..

```
public class ImageController {

    public ImageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

     public String eventLogo{get; set;}
     public String imageURL{get;set;}

  public ImageController()
  {
    imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
    List< document > documentList=[select name from document where 
                                    Name=:eventLogo];

    if(documentList.size()>0)
    {
      imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use Map to put id and name of the document.